# Convertir fecha en milisegundos en fecha formato 'MM DD YYYY 21:31:30'

Tags: postgresql, bash, sh

Quiero transformar la fecha dentro de mi script .sh, ya que necesito subirla a una base de datos Postgresql, porque creo que este no acepta el tipo timestamp en ms. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Intenta proveer un [mcve], así como indicar qué intentaste.

Comment: Tal vez [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371248/how-to-convert-timestamps-to-dates-in-bash) te ayude. Me parece que debes intentar buscar con más ***fe***. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes acceso a un sistema Linux (o, al menos, a GNU `date`), puedes hacer:

```
$ segundos=1552949930
$ fecha=$(date -d @"$segundos" +'%m %d %Y %T')
$ echo "$fecha"
03 18 2019 22:58:50
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien "cambiar la fecha dentro de mi script", ¿Te refieres a que dentro de tu script hay cadenas de la forma <fecha en milisegundos> y las quieres transformar al formato deseado? Si ese es el caso, puedes convertir los milisegundos a segundos y luego estos a la fecha deseada especificada por un formato en el comando `date` y luego reemplazarlo con `sed`, es decir:

```
fecha_mili=1359665533333
fecha_sec=$( bc <<< "scale=3; $fecha_mili / 1000" )
fecha_nueva="$(date --date="@$fecha_sec" +'%m %d %Y %H:%M:%S')"  # que es "01 31 2013 14:52:13"
sed -i "s/$fecha_mili/$fecha_nueva/g"  tu_script.sh
```